# tensorflow 2 how to print tensor value inside tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow 2.3.0.

I implemented my own Layer by inheritting the `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. I implemented my own computation inside the `call` function of my own Layer. Like the demo code below.

Now I want to print tensor values inside the `call` functions. I tried `tf.print`, but nothing was shown. How to print the actual tensor values along with the training. Thanks advance.

```py
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        x=func1(inputs)
        tf.print(x) # not working!
        x=func2(x)
        tf.print(x) # not working!
```

I used the estimator api to train the model.

Comment: tf estimator is not recommended to use with tf 2. It may be the reason you receive such behavior.

Comment: Under normal circumstances (w/o estimator), the tensor should print (tested). If possible, please share a reproducible code.

Comment: Can you put a shrunk version of your `Code` here ?  Which simplifies everything and won't expose the details of your algorithm, except the bug. Or if you don't worry about divulging your own algorithm, you can post it directly.